# Azure Data Factory Git Merge Main into Feature

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I'm working on Azure Data Factory as part of a large team and hitting a problem managing merges which does not seem to make sense.

Scenario
When starting a new feature we create a new branch called, for example, 'feature-001' based off 'main'. We then add only what is needed to that branch to satisfy the new feature then submit a PR to Azure DevOps Git.

From time to time there will be a merge conflict detected. The advice given to resolve this is to go into VSCode and resolve the conflict by doing the following:

Clone down the repo (which pulls down the latest 'main').

Verify that the remote feature-001 branch is there with a

```
git branch -r
```

Which it (obviously) is:

```
PS G:\azure\adf\adf-arm> git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  origin/feature-001
  origin/main
```

Then to do a:

```
PS G:\azure\adf\adf-arm> git switch feature-001   
Switched to a new branch 'feature-001'
Branch 'feature-001' set up to track remote branch 'feature-001' from 'origin'.
```

This creates a local branch 'feature-001', tracking to the upstream, where we are to resolve the conflicts.

Next, in order to see where the conflicts are we are advised to attempt to merge 'main' into the 'feature-001' branch with:

```
git merge main
```

The idea is that whatever was preventing 'feature-001' from being merged into 'main' is going to be identical to whatever prevents 'main' from being merged into 'feature-001'. This way we can resolve the merge conflict right there in VSCode but **ON** the 'feature-001' branch.

Then, when resolved, we should push the fixed branch back to the remote/feature-001 branch. When it's pushed back, Azure DevOps detects the change, re-evaluates the PR and realises that there are now no merge conflicts and the PR can be completed painlessly. This seem like a sensible strategy as it keeps any messiness away from 'main'and ensures that only merge-conflict free (or fixed) commits are merged into 'main' by Azure DevOps.

The problem I am seeing is that when I have set everything up and I do:

```
git merge main
```

I get

```
G:\azure\adf\adf-arm> git merge main  
Already up to date.
```

This does not make sense to me as clearly I have changes in 'feature-001' which are not in 'main'. They don't even have the same commit id:

```
PS G:\azure\adf\adf-arm> git branch -vv
* feature-001 8cc623c [origin/feature-001] Adding pipeline: f001-pipeline
  main        1304c11 [origin/main] Update publish_config.json
```

I know that git will be telling me the correct thing and that I'm missing something, but I can't see what it is. Can some kind soul enlighten me ... please!

Comment: Your local clone is likely out of date. You could prove it by comparing the commits in AzDO with those in your local repo. To fix, with `feature-001` checked out, run the command `git pull`, and then `git merge origin/main`.

Comment: Also, note the subtle distinction between merging `main` into `feature-001` vs the other way around. It doesn't affect the state, which is why both directions work for resolving conflicts, but it does affect what "Already up to date." means. See [Yan Sklyarenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76242636/184546) for an explanation.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I have accepted @Van Skylarenko answer as fundamentally this IS the reason for the issue, but the advice to pull and merge origin/main gets me out of jail beautifully! Really appreciate all the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Already up to date` message shows up when you try to merge the changes in master which are already in your feature branch. I can think of two cases when this can happen:

1. There were no changes to the master branch since you branched out your feature branch. However, in this case you won't face with the merge conflicts, so it doesn't seem to be your case.
2. The latest changes of master have not been pulled locally. When you run `git merge master` it's the local master you operate with. If the latest changes were not pulled from the origin master, you'll not witness those merge conflicts.

I tend to think you face with the case #2. Before doing `git merge master` run `git pull` to pull the most recent changes from the remote.

Comment: I would suggest making sure that both local `feature-001` and local `main` are up to date after the pull, or otherwise merging in `origin/main`.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried both switching and checking out main and making sure I had pulled all changes to main into my local repo. When viewing the files I can actually see the changes (and differences with feature-001 branch). Yet merge still reported already up to date. Very odd.  However your idea of merging in origin/main actually solves the problem beautifully!! This buys me time to figure this out a bit more. Thank you very much!